# Tier 5 - Visa Expired

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have just been refused the Tier 2 sponsorship visa, where I previously had the Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa. I want to come back for a week and a half after my visa has expired to close my accounts, move out etc. Will I have a problem with Immigration? I can seem to find a straight answer.

I can get my old boss to verify for me that I am leaving etc if that is helpful.

Comment: You don’t say how much time you have left before your visa expires but is it  impossible to organise these things without returning? Bank accounts can usually easily be closed online for example.

Comment: Is this really an expats question? The asker wants to make a short visit to the UK to tidy up their affairs.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you should be able to enter the UK as a visa-exempt visitor after the expiration of your tier 5 visa, but you could run into trouble if the officer suspects that you will try to use the visitor status improperly, particularly to work.  It's the officer's duty to presume that this is your intention, and the burden of convincing the officer otherwise falls on you.

To that end, be honest, and have evidence of your plans to settle your affairs in the UK.  For example, correspondence with your bank about closing your accounts, with roommates or your landlord about moving out, or with a shipper about sending your things out of the country could be helpful.  But don't volunteer these things lest you appear over eager.  Just have them at the ready in case the officer asks.

Similarly, any evidence of your plans to move somewhere outside the UK may be helpful, whether evidence of a job search or a housing search out what have you.